# Проверка интернет соединения

Tags: java, android, shell

Вычитал, что можно проверять интернет соединение с помощью

```
android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE
```

Или

```
android.net.ConnectivityManager
```

Но все это только с помощью java. Можно ли реализовать это с помощью Shell?

Comment: делайте тогда ping на 8.8.8.8, ну если вы конечно не в Китае, у них же google вроде как блокирует их великий китайский фаервол)

Comment: Решил не заморачиваться с отдельной проверкой - посылаю запрос и обрабатываю результат.

Answer (score 2):

Можно проверить таким образом

```
public boolean isOnline() {
    ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo netInfo = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    return netInfo != null && netInfo.isConnectedOrConnecting();
}
```

Но, в этом способе проверки есть один большой минус.
Проверяется только подключение к сети(wifi,3g,4g и т.д.)
Если вы будите подключены к WIFI, а интернета не будет, то сервис покажет, что соединение есть. Хотя, по факту его нету.

По поводу PING  - **исполняемый файл добавляют не все производители**. Встречал часто китайские устройства, где нету файла PING.

```
public boolean isOnline() {
    Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
    try {
        Process ipProcess = runtime.exec("/system/bin/ping -c 1 8.8.8.8");
        int     exitValue = ipProcess.waitFor();
        return (exitValue == 0);
    }
    catch (IOException e)          { e.printStackTrace(); }
    catch (InterruptedException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }

    return false;
}
```

Как показывает практика, лучше всего делать запрос на какой-то сайт, например Google.com и отслеживать ответ на предмет **UnknownHostException**

```
public boolean isOnline() {
    try {
        int timeoutMs = 1500;
        Socket sock = new Socket();
        SocketAddress sockaddr = new InetSocketAddress("8.8.8.8", 53);

        sock.connect(sockaddr, timeoutMs);
        sock.close();

        return true;
    } catch (IOException e) { 
        return false; 
    }
}
```

**И не забывайте, что все операции с сетью нужно делать в отдельном потоке**

**И нужно добавить 2 пермишена в Manifests**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

Comment: Но и этого способа есть большой минус. При каждой проверке будет выполняться запрос.

Comment: @Flippy А как ты проверишь без запроса ?
Вся связь устроена на запросах

Answer (score 0):

Возможно покажется костылём, но я считаю, что это самый надёжный способ: отправить запрос на какой-нибудь сайт, который может возвращать какие-то данные (например в формате JSON) и если ответ с сервера приходит, то интернет есть, если выскакивает ошибка, то его нет. Это очень просто реализовать если будешь использовать библиотеку Retrofit 2

Answer (score 0):

У себя проверяю вот так:
правда минус один , как уже писали, проверяет есть ли соединение только на момент срабатывания метода.

```
    /*
 * тут проверяю есть ли сеть
 * if NetworkChecker.isNetworkAvailable(getActivity())) {
 * сеть доступна
 }
 */

public class NetworkChecker {

/** old version to  {@link #isNetworkAvailable} */
public static boolean isConnected(Context context) {
    ConnectivityManager cm =
            (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo activeNetwork = null;
    if (cm != null) {
        activeNetwork = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    }
    return activeNetwork != null && activeNetwork.isConnectedOrConnecting();
}

/**
 * Get the network info
 *
 *
 */

public static NetworkInfo getNetworkInfo(Context context){
    ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    return cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
}

/**
 * Check if there is any connectivity
 *
 *
 */

public static boolean isNetworkAvailable(Context context){
    NetworkInfo info = NetworkChecker.getNetworkInfo(context);
    return (info != null && info.isConnected());
}

/**
 * Check if there is any connectivity to a Wifi network
 *
 */

public static boolean isConnectedWifi(Context context){
    NetworkInfo info = NetworkChecker.getNetworkInfo(context);
    return (info != null && info.isConnected() && info.getType() == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI);
}

/**
 * Check if there is any connectivity to a mobile network
 *
 */

public static boolean isConnectedMobile(Context context){
    NetworkInfo info = NetworkChecker.getNetworkInfo(context);
    return (info != null && info.isConnected() && info.getType() == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE);
}

/**
 * Check if there is fast connectivity
 *
 */

public static boolean isConnectedFast(Context context){
    NetworkInfo info = NetworkChecker.getNetworkInfo(context);
    return (info != null && info.isConnected() && NetworkChecker.isConnectionFast(info.getType(),info.getSubtype()));
}

/**
 * Check if the connection is fast
 *
 */

public static boolean isConnectionFast(int type, int subType){
    if(type==ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI){
        return true;
    }else if(type==ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE){
        switch(subType){
            case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_1xRTT: // ~ 50-100 kbps
            case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_CDMA: // ~ 14-64 kbps
            case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_EDGE: // ~ 50-100 kbps
            case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_GPRS: // ~ 100 kbps
                return false;

            case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_EVDO_0: // ~ 400-1000 kbps
            case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_EVDO_A: // ~ 600-1400 kbps
            case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_HSDPA: // ~ 2-14 Mbps
            case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_HSPA: // ~ 700-1700 kbps
            case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_HSUPA: // ~ 1-23 Mbps
            case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_UMTS: // ~ 400-7000 kbps
                return true;
            /*
             * Above API level 7, make sure to set android:targetSdkVersion
             * to appropriate level to use these
             */
            case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_EHRPD: // API level 11  // ~ 1-2 Mbps
            case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_EVDO_B: // API level 9 // ~ 5 Mbps
            case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_HSPAP: // API level 13 // ~ 10-20 Mbps
            case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_LTE: // API level 11 // ~ 10+ Mbps
                return true;
            case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_IDEN: // API level 8 // ~25 kbps
                return false;
            // Unknown
            case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_UNKNOWN:
            default:
                return false;
        }
    }else{
        return false;
    }
}
    }
```